# curl: (56) Recv failure: Connection reset by peer when podman is running

Tags: node.js, vps, kvm, centos8, podman

I have a problem with my podman on centOS 8.

my Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:14
WORKDIR /home/seadog/html/webiapp
COPY package*.json ./
RUN npm install
COPY . .
EXPOSE 3050
CMD ["node"]
```

I'm running selected image

```
podman run -dt -p 3050:3050 webiapp
```

podman ps show me:

```
CONTAINER ID  IMAGE                     COMMAND  CREATED        STATUS            PORTS                   NAMES
593b1746b57c  localhost/webiapp:latest  node     4 seconds ago  Up 4 seconds ago  0.0.0.0:3050->3050/tcp  blissful_meitner
```

My app works corectly because when I try run nodemon in app direcotry i receive this message:

```
Error: listen EADDRINUSE: address already in use :::3050
```

but when I try open my app on browser or using curl in this way curl -i localhost:3050 I recieve this error:

```
curl: (56) Recv failure: Connection reset by peer
```

any ideas?